# 6-BIT (or 5 bit) encode and decode to/from strings for packing into 128 bit pseudo-GUIDs

Tags: vba, guid

(Apologies if this is a repeat but my question disappeared- THIS ONE IS MORE DETAILED)
I have names that need conversation into a 'static' of 'fixed' GUID. Using ASCII- I have a GUID that represents a a 16-character name. I can re-run these in reverse to see if it is one of our names. But I would like to expand it so I only use an indexed set of characters, and can effectively jam 16 characters into the 128 bits of the GUID (ASCII-8 bit - FF in hex, easy to fake and parse) I am only using 64 characters which I could reduce to 6 bit if I could figure out how to pack the bits in VBA/EXCEL. I could lower that to 5-bit potentially if I dropped the caps.

With 6 or 5 bit, I could get names that were 128/5=25(r3) bits or 128/6=21(r2) bits, or is this even possible?
so the indexes would look like:

```
''stripped character index tables
'''''''''''''''''''0'''''''''1'''''''''2'''''''''3'
'''''''''''''''''''0123456789x123456789x123456789x1
Const b32_5_bit = "()+.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_" '' basic text only naming

'''''''''''''''''''0'''''''''1'''''''''2'''''''''3'''''''''4'''''''''5'''''''''6'''
'''''''''''''''''''0123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123
Const b64_6_bit = ".0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   ''Text and numbers naming

'''''''''''''''''''0'''---''''''1'''''''''2'''''''''3'''''''''4'''''''''5'''''''''6'''''''''7'''''''''8'''''''''9'''''''''0'''''''''1'''''''''2
'''''''''''''''''''0123---456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123459789x123456789x12345978
Const b128_7_bit = " !""""#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcedfghijklmnopqrstufwxyz{|}~" ''Full printable characters for naming ''And on to more unused spaces....
```

I cannot figure out how to pack the bits in VBA so they can be unpacked. Tried masking against
2^6(n-1)+ 2^(Return index of character in array)

where (n) is the position in the string masking. This encoded but didn't decode correctly.

I am About to revert to a hack where I convert to string representation of binary and then nibble 6 characters at a time and convert back to the index. e.g. ".a" = "000000" & "100100"

Looked at hashing - but that doesn't reverse(for back checks)- and a few other things - and been trying to wrap my head around the ins and out of 6-bit base64 numbering. Any help is appreciated.

Here is what I had for the Text to GUID(base256-8-bit):

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Base16"
Option Explicit

Const HEX_STRING_PREFIX As String = "0x"
Const VBA_HEX_PREFIX As String = "&h"

''UUID record layout                  total numbers =32
''Name                                Length (bytes) Length (hex digits)Contents
''time_low                            4              8                  integer giving the low 32 bits of the time
''time_mid                            2              4                  integer giving the middle 16 bits of the time
''time_hi_and_version                 2              4                  4-bit "version" in the most significant bits, followed by the high 12 bits of the time
''clock_seq_hi_and_res clock_seq_low  2              4                  1–3-bit "variant" in the most significant bits, followed by the 13–15-bit clock sequence
''node                                6              12                 the 48-bit node id

Public Function GUIDfromStr(Prefix As String, Variable As String) As String
    ''encodes decodeable GUID based on previx and a variable to run out to end of line (as many characters as possible)
    ''Used to generate GUIDS or UUIDs in a way that is identifiable
    ''PREFIX Is KTGY
    ''Variable is N...characters of variable name to encode to HEX for use as a GUID in parameter name generation. Not random but still random enough to backtrack.
    ''ASCII letters are encoded in hex pairs(0-255) and truncated
    Prefix = UCase(Left(Prefix, 4))
    
    GUIDfromStr = HexEncode(Prefix, "") & HexEncode(Variable, "")
    GUIDfromStr = Left(GUIDfromStr & String(32, "0"), 32)
    GUIDfromStr = Format(GUIDfromStr, String(8, "&") & "-" & String(4, "&") & "-" & String(4, "&") & "-" & String(4, "&") & "-" & String(12, "&"))
    

End Function

Public Function STRfromGUID(str As String) As String
''conver the first 8 characters, add a separator convert the remaining to reval up to 26 characters of parameter name
    str = Replace(str, "-", "") ''remove the dashes
    STRfromGUID = HexDecode(HEX_STRING_PREFIX & Left(str, 8)) _
                & "|" _
                & HexDecode(HEX_STRING_PREFIX & Right(str, Len(str) - 8))
End Function

Public Function HexEncode(AsciiText As String, Optional HexPrefix As String = HEX_STRING_PREFIX) As String

  If AsciiText = vbNullString Then

    HexEncode = AsciiText

  Else

    Dim asciiChars() As Byte
    asciiChars = StrConv(AsciiText, vbFromUnicode)

    ReDim hexChars(LBound(asciiChars) To UBound(asciiChars)) As String

    Dim char As Long
    For char = LBound(asciiChars) To UBound(asciiChars)
      hexChars(char) = Right$("00" & Hex$(asciiChars(char)), 2)
    Next char

    HexEncode = HexPrefix & Join(hexChars, "")
  End If

End Function

Public Function HexDecode(HexString As String, Optional HexPrefix As String = HEX_STRING_PREFIX)

  'Check if there's anything to decode

  If HexString = vbNullString Then
    HexDecode = vbNullString
    Exit Function
  Else

    If Not StrComp(Left$(HexString, Len(HexPrefix)), HexPrefix, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      'Unexpected string format
      GoTo DecodeError
    End If

    Dim hexRaw As String
    hexRaw = Mid$(HexString, 1 + Len(HexPrefix))

    'Check if the string is valid for decoding
    If Len(hexRaw) Mod 2 = 1 Then
      GoTo DecodeError
    End If

    Dim numHexChars As Long
    numHexChars = Len(hexRaw) / 2

    ReDim hexChars(0 To numHexChars - 1) As Byte
    Dim char As Long
    For char = 0 To numHexChars - 1
      Dim hexchar As String
      hexchar = VBA_HEX_PREFIX & Mid$(hexRaw, 1 + char * 2, 2)
      'Check if the hex-pair is actually hex
      If Not IsNumeric(hexchar) Then
        GoTo DecodeError
      End If
      hexChars(char) = CByte(hexchar)
    Next char
    'Return the concatenated bytes as a string
    HexDecode = StrConv(hexChars, vbUnicode)

  End If

SafeExit:
  Exit Function

DecodeError:
  HexDecode = CVErr(xlErrValue)

End Function
```

Comment: I may have figured it out... based on the number of bits i.e. 2^(n) I can subtract that value from the decimal to get to the next group of (n)bits.
Places-> 6 64  Dec2BIN  
0 0 0 0 000000  
1 0 0 1 000001  
17 0 0 17 010001  
63 0 0 63 111111  
64 1 64 0 000000 =Value-(INT(Value/factor)*factor) =Value+(Position*factor)
65 1 64 1 000001 =Value-(Position*factor) 
81 1 64 17 010001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Attribute VB_Name = "base2_6"
''Total hack- BUT it works to jam 21 characters using a 6 bit reference
''into a 128bit GUID
''Characters register 6 bit binary MSB at left,
''every 8 bits gets jammed into a HEX and those bits removed off the stack
''when max characters is reached- there are 2 bits left over - filled with
''LSB "00" to force the HEX to generate for 32 characters of hex for
''A 128 bit GUID. Will work on the round trip next to convert from GUID
''to string - 5 more characters than a straight ASCII to hex conversion

Option Explicit
''Background - to create as long of a static GUID from a string (21)
''Base 2^6 = 6 bit, 64 characters, # 0-63
''decode = Value - (CharPosition*Base)
''Encode = Value + (CharPosition*Base)

'look at 24 bit chunks (6bit and 8bit share every 24 bits bit group.)
'00000x00000x00000x00000x       = every four characters in 6 bit = 24 bits
'0000000x0000000x0000000x       = 3 bytes
'-2hex--x-2hex--x-2hex--x       = 3 hex bytes per 4 characters
'128bit = 16 hex pairs or 21 characters + 2 leftover bits.
Const vbqt = """"
''Full VISUAL ASCII characters from 32(space) through 126 ~
Const strASC = " !" & vbqt & "#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
''Revit illegal chars "Filesystem"                   :;< >?                           [\]  `                          {|}
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''5 bit - would allow for 25 charqacters simplified- ignoring upper and lower case
''would require a UCASE convert prior to checking. can contain a few digits only
''Optional simpler base 5bit- not used - do not change this - it will change the whole field base and compression!
''do not change this - it will change the whole field base and compression!
''''''''''''''''0''''''''1'''''''''2'''''''''3'*<31 MAX (32 CHARS)
''''''''''''''''01234567890123456789012345678901 ''NoSpaces!
Const Base5b = ".0123ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_"
Const x5b = 5   ''Encoding bitsize
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''6 bit - allows for 21 charqacters simplified- ignoring upper and lower case
''do not change this - it will change the whole field base and compression!
''''''''''''''''00''''''''1'''''''''2'''''''''3'''''''''4'''''''''5'''''''''6''''
''''''''''''''''0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123  ''NoSpaces!
Const Base6b = ".0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Const x6b = 6   ''Encoding bitsize
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''7 bit - would only allow for 18 characters
''do not change this - it will change the whole field base and compression!
''''''''''''''''00           ''''''''1'''''''''2'''''''''3'''''''''4'''''''''5'''''''''6'''''''''7'''''''''''12      *<127
''''''''''''''''01    2       34567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789---01234567
Const Base7b = " !" & vbqt & "#$%&'()*+.123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Const x7b = 7   ''Encoding bitsize
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''8 bit - allows for 256 characters
''Same as straight hex encoding xFF 256 bits - mostly 173 wasted spaces
''''''''''''''''0------------''''''''1'''''''''2'''''''''3'''''''''4'''''''''5'''''''''6'''''''''7'''''''''8'''
''''''''''''''''0----1-------2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
Const Base8b = "!" & vbqt & "#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;=@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Function Encode6Bit2HexGUID(VarName As String) As String ''Range) As String ''guid in HEX
''takes a string of fixed characters Base6b compared against 6 bits to compress 4 characters for every 3 Bytes (FFFFFF)
''To pack into 128 bit string for GUID.
Dim i           As Integer          ''count integer
Dim ie          As Integer          ''iend of count either  MaxChar or less
Dim strName     As String           ''string to nibble
Dim HexStr      As String           ''Hex string to build
        
Const MaxChar = 21

Dim enc6b       As Long             ''6bit value per character
    
Dim binStr      As String           ''Binary representation of number
''strName = VarName.value  ''get value to work with
strName = VarName
    If Len(strName) > MaxChar Then
        MsgBox MaxChar & " character limite exceeded, variables must be unique within the first  MaxChar characters.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Warning"
        '
        ie = MaxChar
        strName = Left(strName, MaxChar)
    Else
        ie = Len(Left(strName, MaxChar)) '''''''''''''''''''<<<<<<<<<<<<<<DEBUG test
        'If ie < 4 Then ie = 4 ''need every 4 characters to make up 3 hex pairs
        ie = Round((ie / 4) + 0.5, 0) * 4
    End If


For i = 1 To ie       ''loop thorugh string name
    enc6b = enc6Bc(Mid(strName, i, 1))  ''Get char position in matrix
    binStr = binStr & Dec2Bin(enc6b, 6) ''ENCODE 6 BIT BINARY
    
    If i = MaxChar Then binStr = binStr & "00"   ''force last two bits  1 & 2 to register to process byte
    ''check if 8 or more binaries to byte into a hex
    Do While Len(binStr) >= 8
        HexStr = HexStr & Right("0" & Hex(Bin2Dec(Left(binStr, 8))), 2)
        binStr = Right(binStr, Len(binStr) - 8)
    Loop

Next i

Encode6Bit2HexGUID = Left(HexStr & String(32, "0"), 32)
'''''''''0            1              2              3
'''''''''12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56 78 90 12
''guid = XX.XX.XX.XX-XX.XX-XX.XX-XX.XX-XX.XX.XX.XX.XX.XX

''format GUID
Encode6Bit2HexGUID = Format(Encode6Bit2HexGUID, String(8, "&") & "-" & String(4, "&") & "-" & String(4, "&") & "-" & String(4, "&") & "-" & String(12, "&"))

End Function

Function enc6Bc(X As String) As Integer
    enc6Bc = InStr(1, Base6b, Left(X, 1), vbBinaryCompare) - 1
    If enc6Bc = -1 Then enc6Bc = 0            ''substitute 1st character if not found (returns 0)
End Function

Function Dec2Bina(X As Long, BitNo As Integer) As String
''RA: MAY TAKE A HEAVIER COMPUTATIONAL TOLL THAN THE DIVIDE/2 METHOD
Dim i
For i = BitNo - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If X >= 2^ ^ i Then
        X = X - 2^ ^ i
        Dec2Bina = Dec2Bina & "1"
    Else
        Dec2Bina = Dec2Bina & "0"
    End If
Next i
End Function

'Decimal To Binary
' =================
' Source: http://groups.google.ca/group/comp.lang.visual.basic/browse_thread/thread/28affecddaca98b4/979c5e918fad7e63
' Author: Randy Birch (MVP Visual Basic)
' NOTE: You can limit the size of the returned
'              answer by specifying the number of bits
Function Dec2Bin(ByVal DecimalIn As Variant, _
              Optional NumberOfBits As Variant) As String
    Dec2Bin = ""
    DecimalIn = Int(CDec(DecimalIn))
    Do While DecimalIn <> 0
        Dec2Bin = Format$(DecimalIn - 2 * Int(DecimalIn / 2)) & Dec2Bin
        DecimalIn = Int(DecimalIn / 2)  ''SHIFT ONE BIT TO THE LEFT WITH DIV2
    Loop
    If Not IsMissing(NumberOfBits) Then
       If Len(Dec2Bin) > NumberOfBits Then
          Dec2Bin = "Error - Number exceeds specified bit size"
       Else
          Dec2Bin = Right$(String$(NumberOfBits, _
                    "0") & Dec2Bin, NumberOfBits)
       End If
    End If
End Function

'Binary To Decimal
' =================
Function Bin2Dec(BinaryString As String) As Variant
    Dim X As Integer
    For X = 0 To Len(BinaryString) - 1
        Bin2Dec = CDec(Bin2Dec) + Val(Mid(BinaryString, _
                  Len(BinaryString) - X, 1)) * 2 ^ X
    Next
End Function

Public Function String_from_6Bit2HexGUID(strGUID As String) As String
Dim i           As Integer
Dim strBin      As String
Dim str3byte    As String
Dim Long3Byte   As Long
Dim strVarName  As String
    strGUID = Replace(strGUID, "-", "") ''remove the dashes
    For i = 1 To Len(strGUID) Step 6
        str3byte = Left(strGUID, 6)
        strGUID = Right(strGUID, Len(strGUID) - Len(str3byte))
        Long3Byte = CLng("&H" & str3byte)
        If i = 31 Then
            strBin = Left(Dec2Bin(Long3Byte, 8), 6)
        Else
            strBin = Dec2Bin(Long3Byte, 24)
        End If
        Do While strBin > ""
           strVarName = strVarName & Mid(Base6b, Bin2Dec(Left(strBin, 6)) + 1, 1)
           strBin = Right(strBin, Len(strBin) - 6)
        Loop
    Next i
    String_from_6Bit2HexGUID = strVarName
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''Testing funcitons for in and back
Private Sub test_Encode6Bit2Hex()
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''0        1         2
                               '123456789012345687901<MAX
    Debug.Print Encode6Bit2HexGUID("zzzz................z")
    '''''''''''''''''''''''equals = FFFFFF00-0000-0000-0000-0000000000FC
End Sub

Private Sub test_String_from_6Bit2HexGUID()
Const StrEncode = "__.CLEAR.HARD12345678"
'''''''''''''''''''0        1         2
                  '123456789012345687901<MAX
    Debug.Print StrEncode
    Debug.Print Encode6Bit2HexGUID(StrEncode)
    Debug.Print String_from_6Bit2HexGUID(Encode6Bit2HexGUID(StrEncode))
End Sub

Private Sub printASCII()
Dim i
Dim str
For i = 32 To 126
str = str & Chr(i)
Next i
Debug.Print str
End Sub
```